# Change div attribute to random string before script loads having issues with CORS/Security I believe

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to implement a chat script into my site and I need to have the div attribute `data-channel` changed to a random string before the script loads on my page. I cannot seem to get this to work I think due to browser security. I have tried creating and appending with `document.createElement("script")` and `document.createElement("div")` with a random string being passed into the `data-channel=` attribute. Not sure how to proceed and would appreciate any insight. here is what the script should look like when it runs https://jsfiddle.net/2g71a9pq/1/ and it should initiate a random channel up top. the full script and div code also below. Thanks!

```
 <div id="tlkio" data-channel="randomstringhere" data-theme="theme--night" style="width:100%;height:400px;">
    <script async src="https://tlk.io/embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: you should probably have a function that changes the attribute and then loads the script dynamically.

Comment: After your html element you can add a javascript code to change the attribute and then load the script you want below

Comment: What @schieben said, but emphasis on running your JS that creates the random string BEFORE you include your chat script.